# How it would be possible to resize children to fit the parent panel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have a panel, which has a dynamic number of children. I want to make children to expand (to defined max height) or shrink to fit it's parent panel.

[image: Max dimensions of desired image]

The problem:

[image: Added more same images and they overflow over panel boundaries]

Basically, I want those images to scale down, just to fit the panel above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [Vertical Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) on your parent object ?